# Software for recording video games?

Tags: windows, cross-platform

Need a software for capturing video games footage as I play.

Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxQLzqpQ9GQ)

Should be compatible with Windows OS.  Would be recording FIFA footage, but it would be nice, if there is a software which is compatible with all/most of the video games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Open Broadcast Software](https://obsproject.com/). It's open source and cross platform. Contain's plugin's too so you can customize other things as you like.

> What is OBS?
>
> Open Broadcaster Software is free and open source software for video
>   recording and live streaming. Supported features include:
>
> Encoding using H264 (x264) and AAC. Support for Intel Quick Sync Video
>   (QSV) and NVENC. Unlimited number of scenes and sources. Live RTMP
>   streaming to Twitch, YouTube, DailyMotion, Hitbox and more. File
>   output to MP4 or FLV. GPU-based game capture for high performance game
>   streaming. DirectShow capture device support (webcams, capture cards,
>   etc). Windows 8 high speed monitor capture support. Bilinear or
>   lanczos3 resampling.

Comment: Cool application, but a little hard to use, it takes me a while to figure out how to fix the Black screen issue: https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/wiki/Laptop-Performance-Issues
And have to add "Game Capture" to capture game. But good application, I tried NVidia Shadowplay and realize ShadowPlay can only capture its supported games, I tried Fraps but the video size of Fraps is too large. so OBS is a life saver - it fit me perfectly.